# What are linux command to get following output?

Tags: linux, shell

I have following type of text pattern in a text file on Linux. I need to get only last part of this text. How can I get that?

```
tmk.mfg.pref.ZPreferes::getKey
com.sun.star.uno.SCompentCont::getSage
com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory::createInstanceWithContext
```

I need only last part of each line i.e. getKey, getSage, etc. Can anyone tell me how to get it with cut or any other command.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 10 questions, all of which are not accepted. Take care of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One liner bash script:

```
for line in $(cat test); do echo ${line//*::}; done
```

Comment: This assumes no white spaces in the lines.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want to program a bash script for this since you are posting it on stack overflow. Of course you will never the less still get a one liner.

I would have used grep

```
grep -o -e "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" TEXTFILE.TXT
```

Note that the regexp I am using is for a standard identifier in java/c/c++ change it to suit your need.

Comment: No underscore in an identifier?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it into `cut`: `[...] | cut -d: -f3`

Comment: its not working it gives first part of line text i.e. in above case it gives tmk.mfg.pref.ZPreferes, com.sun.star.uno.SCompentCont.. can u tell me another solution?

Comment: That would return the first field, which in this instance is tmk.mfg.pref.ZPreferes etc, I think you meant `-f3`

Comment: @beny23: D'oh, typo... Prajkata: Sorry about that, should work now

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either **`sed`**:

```
sed --expression='s/.*://'
```

or **`awk`**:

```
awk -F: '{ print $NF }'
```

Or, if you explicitly want the *third* colon-separated field (instead of the *last* field):

```
awk -F: '{ print $3 }'
```

Or, if you want to use only **`bash`** builtins:

```
while read line; do echo "${line##*:}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line; do 
  echo "${line##*:}"  # removes everything up to and including the last colon
done < input.file
```